# How to "remove exception" from Light Table editor using keyboard only?

Tags: lighttable

In Light Table version 0.8.1, say I'll evaluate clojure code like (resolve inc) and get an exception like in the picture. Now I can't see anything else on the whole screen.

[image: exception in light table taking up most of the screen]

I can right click it, choose "remove exception", but that means I have to get hand on the mouse.
Or I can hit ctrl + s, save (which I might actualy not want to) and lose the exception but also all results of other evaluations. There is nothing in keymap, as far as I can figure.

So - can I do the equivalent of mouse action just using keyboard?
This feels like punishment for coding something wrong :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished with the command `Eval: Clear inline results`, but it will clear all the other inline results as well as the exception.

It is possible to map the command to a keybinding. Add something like the following to your user keymap:

`[:editor "pmeta-i" :clear-inline-results]`

After the keymaps have been reloaded, you should be able to then use `Ctrl`-`i` (or `Cmd`-`i`) to clear the inline results.

If you are not familiar with the user keymap, it can be accessed via the command `Settings: User keymap`.

From what I can tell, Light Table does not currently have a command to clear inline results based on the cursor's location, but it would be useful. Please consider opening an issue on Github for this.

Comment: Thanks. Better than nothing. I considered and opened an issue https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/issues/2319